# Server authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, authentication, cookies

I am in the process of learning ASP .NET with Blazor. So, I started the creation of a small project with a connection to an administrator account to be able to dynamically change the content of the site. So I use a REST API to make the connection with the database.
My problem is that when I create the Claims on the server side in order to be able to authenticate myself as admin, they are not taken into account and User.Identity.AuthenticationType is null. Yet, I am sure that the code containing the creation of ClaimsPrincipal is executed.

I post here the code of UserController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Portfolio.API.Attributes;
using Portfolio.API.Contexts;
using Portfolio.Models;

namespace Portfolio.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PortfolioContext _context;

        public UserController(PortfolioContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("{login}/{hashedPassword}")]
        public ActionResult<User> GetUser(string login, string hashedPassword)
        {
            hashedPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(hashedPassword);
            if (_context.Users.Count() != 0)
            {
                var result = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Login == login && el.Password == hashedPassword);


                if (result == null)
                {
                    var result2 = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(el => el.Login == login);
                    if (result2 != null)
                    {
                        result2.NumberConnectionTry++;
                        _context.Users.Update(result2);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                else if(result.NumberConnectionTry == 3)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                result.NumberConnectionTry = 0;
                _context.Users.Update(result);
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        }

        [HttpPost("loginuser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> LoginUser(User user)
        {
            User loggedUser = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Login == user.Login && u.Password == user.Password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if(loggedUser != null)
            {
                var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loggedUser.Login);
                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { claim }, "serverAuth");
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(loggedUser);
        }

        [HttpGet("logoutuser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<String>> LogoutUser()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return "Success";
        }

        [HttpGet("getcurrentuser")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetCurrentUser()
        {
            User currentUser = new User();
            Console.WriteLine(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(User.Identity.AuthenticationType);
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("toto");
                Console.WriteLine("Toti : " + User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name).ToString());
                currentUser.Login = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(currentUser);
        }

    }
}
```

And here the code of Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Portfolio.API.Contexts;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Portfolio.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<PortfolioContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Portfolio.API", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Portfolio.API v1"));
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();


            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

If you need more info on the subject, don't hesitate to ask me!
Thanks for taking the time to read my problem.

UPDATE :

When I set a breakpoint on top of LoginUser I have the following User :
[image]

And now if I set a breakpoint right after HttpContext.SignInAsync, I have the following User and ClaimPrincipal :

[image]

Comment: Is the ClaimPrincipal user object null when you hit the API?

Comment: I have updated my initial post with my ClaimPrincipal data.

Comment: You're not authenticated. IsAuthenticated is false. This looks like a Core app so you'll have to use some type of provider to authenticate. Just calling Signin via OWIN isn't going to persist your tokens/cookies. Look into ApplicationUserManager and SigninMananger